# Incompatible pointer types initializing 'CGContextRef *'

Tags: objective-c, cgcontextref

Not gonna lie, I'm trying to follow a tutorial in a book and I can't get past this warning.

`Incompatible pointer types initializing 'CGContextRef *' (aka 'struct CGContext **') with an expression of type 'CGContextRef' (aka 'struct CGContext *')`

The offending line is: `CGContextRef *imageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();`

```
- (IBAction)hide:(id)sender {
    CGContextRef *imageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    if (_myIcon.alpha == 1) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:imageContext];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        _myIcon.alpha = 0.0;
        [_hideButton setTitle:@"Show" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else if (_myIcon.alpha == 0.0) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:imageContext];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        _myIcon.alpha = 1;
        [_hideButton setTitle:@"Hide" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: BTW - you need a newer book. The use of `UIView beginAnimations:context:` and `UIView commitAnimations` is discouraged. It is much better to use the newer block-based animation methods of `UIView`.

Comment: @rmaddy Copyright 2013... that sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGContextRef` is not a class. You don't need the pointer. Change this:

```
CGContextRef *imageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

to:

```
CGContextRef imageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Look at the docs for the `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` function. The return type is `CGContextRef`, not `CGContextRef *`.

Comment: Thank you, this is a typo in the book.

Comment: Look at the website for the book. Typically there is an errata section pointing out mistakes.